# Parse localDatastore returns 1 object only

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2

I have a podcast app.  When a user taps a subscribe button, I execute this code on my objects:

```
    PFObject.pinAllInBackground(self.episodesToSendToParse)
    PFObject.saveAllInBackground(self.episodesToSendToParse)
```

in my main view controller, which is a `PFQueryTableViewController` I have the following condensed code:

```
class MainTableViewController:  PFQueryTableViewController  {
 override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.parseClassName = "Podcast"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.textKey = "name"
    self.imageKey = "artwork"
    self.paginationEnabled = true
    self.objectsPerPage = 50
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    print("view will appear")
    if (PFUser.currentUser() != nil) {
        self.loadObjects()
        print("reloading")
    }
}



override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Podcast")
    query.fromLocalDatastore()
   query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    return query
}

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? PFTableViewCell
    if cell == nil {
        print("cell not created")
     cell = PFTableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }


    if let name = object?["name"] as? String {
        cell!.textLabel!.text = name
    }

    if let artist = object?["artist"] as? String {
        cell!.detailTextLabel!.text = artist
    }
return cell!
}
}
```

The problem is that only one podcast gets returned in my tableView, which is the last-saved podcast. If I disable queryForTable(), data will be pulled from Parse online and it will load fine. I have checked the `ParseOfflineStore`database in the simulator folder and all the data is there. I am not sure what I can do at this point.

localDatastore is activated in the AppDelegate of course.

Edit: I was wong. All the data isn't saved correctly in the local data store. All the podcast Episodes are saved correctly but I save the parent Podcast recursively and yet it just replaces the previous Podcast. It doesn't add a new entry in the database. Here is the method I use to save Podcast:

```
class SaveToParse {
let podcastClass = "Podcast"
let episodesClass = "Episodes"
var episodesToSendToParse = [PFObject]()

func savePodcastToParse(name: String, artist: String, summary: String, feedURL: String, artworkURL: String, date: NSDate, episodes: [MWFeedItem], artwork: PFFile) {

    let currentP = PFObject(className: self.podcastClass)
    currentP["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
    currentP["name"] = name
    currentP["artist"] = artist
    currentP["summary"] = summary
    currentP["feedURL"] = feedURL
    currentP["artworkURL"] = artworkURL
  //  currentP["artwork"] = artwork
    currentP["date"] = date


    for episode in episodes {
        let episodesToParse = PFObject(className: self.episodesClass)
        episodesToParse["showDate"] = episode.date
        episodesToParse["title"] = episode.title
        episodesToParse["downloadURL"] =
        episode.enclosures[0].valueForKey("url") as? String
        episodesToParse["showNotes"] = episode.summary
        episodesToParse["localPath"] = ""
        episodesToParse["isDownloaded"] = "no"
        episodesToParse["parent"] = currentP
        self.episodesToSendToParse.append(episodesToParse)
        self.episodesToSendToParse.append(currentP)
    }
    PFObject.pinAllInBackground(self.episodesToSendToParse)
    PFObject.saveAllInBackground(self.episodesToSendToParse)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement numberOfRowsInSection: of UITableViewDataSource like so:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 
    return self.episodesToSendToParse.count
}
```

Comment: Since `PFQueryTableViewController` uses an array of objects (`self.objects`) to populate the tableview, I've used `return self.objects!.count` but that hasn't changed a thing. I believe `PFQueryTableViewController` sets this behind the scenes and I shouldn't need to implement `numberOfRowsInSection` anyway. The problem is still here sadly.

Comment: I would agree with this logic though if nothing at all was displayed, but if I disable the localdatastore and let parse populate data from the web then everything works fine